# How to add line through when checkbox is clicked? as i'm new to react

Tags: reactjs

render(){

return(

## TODOLIST

{this.state.items.map(function(items,index){

return(

{items}

<input type="checkbox" onClick={checkboxStyle(items.checked)}checked={items.checked}

onChange={this.handleItemClick.bind(this)}  />

<input type="button" value ="Remove" onClick={this.delete.bind(this)}

data-key={index}/>

)

},this)}

);

}

}
function checkboxStyle(checked) {

return {

textDecorationLine: 'line-through'

};
}

Answer (score 0):

Your function checkboxStyle has been executed but it return an style object to onClick event listener. That's not the way to apply css style.
You have a lot of choice to apply css style by

1. Inline style e.g. <input style={checkboxStyle(items.checked)} .../>

   If items' state changed, reactjs will re-render and execute checkboxStyle to
   return a style object

   P.S. Make sure checkboxStyle function has some logic to return the suitable style.
2. Apply css class e.g. <input className={items.checked ? 'check' : ''} .../>
3. Third party library e.g. styled-components, material-ui (withStyle) etc which can turn javascript to css